# discord.js V12 topic change

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently making a Discord bot that allows you to host a
Simon Says event! However, currently, I'm having an issue:

If you do **, ss startevent** *(the command to start a new event)*, I run the following code:

```
if (args[0].toLowerCase() === "startevent") {

    if (permissionLevel(message.member) < 4) return message.channel.send("**Error:** You don't have permission to do this!");
    
    var ssChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "simon-says");
    if (!(ssChannel)) return message.channel.send("**Error:** Couldn't find the Simon Says channel!");

    if (!(eventStatus(ssChannel) === "Inactive")) return message.channel.send("**Error:** There is already an event active!");

    // ssChannel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Verified"), {
    //     SEND_MESSAGES: false,
    //     VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
    //     READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true
    // });

    var startingTopic = updateStatus(ssChannel, "Starting");
    ssChannel.setTopic(startingTopic);
    ssChannel.setTopic("**DEBUG**");
    message.channel.send("**Succesfully started a new Simon Says event!**");
    ssChannel.send(`Starting a new **Simon Says** event in **5 minutes**! To enter the event, go to <#703168301634945097> and type: **${prefix}ss enter**!`);

    setTimeout(function () {
        ssChannel.send(`Starting a new **Simon Says** event in **1 minute**! To enter the event, go to <#703168301634945097> and type: **${prefix}ss enter**!`);

        setTimeout(function () {
            ssChannel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "SS: Participant"), {
                SEND_MESSAGES: true,
                VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
                READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true
            });

            ssChannel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Verified"), {
                SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
                READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: false
            });

            var activeTopic = updateStatus(ssChannel, "Active");
            ssChannel.setTopic(activeTopic);

            ssChannel.send(`The **Simon Says** event has started! You can now talk!`);
            ssChannel.send("[<@&787000309108965418>]")

        }, 60000)
    }, 240000)
}
```

So, you can see I update the topic of the channel, for debugging I even changed it to "**DEBUG**".
However, it won't update the topic. The topic just stays the same and it doesn't update.

Answer (score 1):

Discord recently changed their rate limit for channel names and topics.
As of 05/28/2020 they have made the rate limit for editing channel names and topics limited to 2 updates per 10 minutes per channel. They made an announcement a while back about this in their Discord Developers discord server.

Comment: Here's the Discord's documentation on rate limiting which may be helpful depending on your design: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits